# Перевод предупреждения при повторном закрытии вопроса

Tags: дефект, локализация

Наткнувшись в очереди на очередной вопрос о загрузке Visual Studio, которых сейчас как грибов по осени, хотел проголосовать за закрытие и отметить как дубликат.

Но т.к. делал все это с мобильного указал не тот вопрос в дубликате.

Вернулся чтобы исправить, отозвал голос за закрытие и хотел проголосовать повторно и указать верный адрес вопроса, но получил следующее сообщение.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И вопрос не в том, что повторное голосование невозможно, а в том, что данное сообщение необходимо перевести.

> You cannot vote to close again after retracting your vote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В последнее время локализация немножко встала, поэтому я решил взять дело в свои руки.

Зарегистрировался в traducir и предложил там, свой вариант перевода:

с

> You cannot vote to close again after retracting your vote

на

> Вы не можете повторно проголосовать за закрытие вопроса после отзыва своего голоса

Ссылка на перевод:

https://ru.traducir.win/strings/17551

<strike>Однако, насколько я понимаю, необходимо чтобы его кто-то заапрувил</strike>

**UPDATE:** подтверждено. ожидаем публикации